# Visual Basic - URL showing when click on a link

Tags: vb.net, url, browser

Just wonder if you could help.

Basically I have a little project to finish, I have created a web browser with VB.NET, when I navigate let's say Google.com, I click to open a link on Google's website and it opens in a new page which is fine but the TextBox on my project (where the URL goes) does not appear any URL to which page/website I've gone to.

Can someone help me on this please?

Thank you so much!

Marco

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a handle to the `Navigated` event of the `WebBrowser`.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()
End Sub
```

The [WebBrowser.Navigated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is raised when the control has navigated to a new document and has begun loading it.